# how to get facebook access_token from returned url when log in using web api

Tags: oauth, asp.net-mvc-5, identity, access-token, asp.net-web-api2

I'm implementing Individual account authentications on Web API project, this should support external logins (facebook, google etc.)

The client consuming the web API is MVC application. Now when user click on Facebook Login I redirect user to host/api/Account/ExternalLogin?provider=Facebook&response_type=token&client_id=self&....

the return URL contains #access_token=.....

now I can't find a way to read this access_token to use it in subsequent requests to API.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

.Net Identity and OWIN middleware handles this for you.

Try this:

```
var loginInfo = _authenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfo();
            if (loginInfo == null)
            {
                return InternalServerError();
            }
```

Try debugging and you should see the access token in the claims within loginInfo